# Applying for an Indian business visa with a German passport from the USA

Tags: visas, india, business-travel, german-citizens, us-residents

I live in the USA and have a German passport. I would like to apply for a business visa for India. Which consulate/mission/embassy do I have to send my documents to? In Germany or in the US? The company is located in the USA.

Also: Does the duration for which the visa is valid differ depending on the embassy?

Answer (score 1):

Visa applicants are generally supposed to apply to the consulate that has jurisdiction over their place of *residence.*  You should therefore apply in the US.

India has outsourced its visa processing in the US to a private company.  The website is https://www.in.ckgs.us/.

When visa duration varies, it generally depends on the applicant's nationality, not on the place where the application was submitted or the visa issued.

You may want to consider whether an e-Visa would suit your needs.  This was formerly called the e-Tourist Visa; its current name reflects the fact that it also serves travelers who visit India for a "casual business visit."  For more information: https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html.

Comment: Thank you for the provided link. I used their contact form. E-Visa is not sufficient as I need to go multiple times over the next year(s) and I don't want to apply for a visa every time.